# dplyr::select_ very slow on short, wide data frame

Tags: r, performance, tidyr

I ended up with a strange case where I was repeatedly running select_ on short (~20 rows), wide (~20K columns) data.frames to grab about 50 columns, and noticed dplyr::select_ was running weirdly slow.

```
df <- cbind(1:20, matrix(rnorm(20000 * 20), nrow = 20, ncol = 20000)) %>%
    data.frame
names(df) <- c("id", paste0("v", 1:20000))
selectcols <- c("id", paste0("v", sample(1:20000, 50)))

system.time(dfshort1 <- df[,selectcols])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.004   0.000   0.000 

system.time(dfshort2 <- df %>%
                select_(.dots = paste0("~", selectcols) %>%
                            lapply(as.formula)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  69.752   0.008  69.773

identical(data.frame(dfshort1), data.frame(dfshort2))
#    TRUE
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps because `select_` is now [deprecated](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/se-deprecated.html)?

Comment: An alternative is `df %>% select(one_of(selectcols) )`

Comment: @aosmith perfect, thanks!